# Sub-subdomain with nginx ingress on Kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, subdomain, cloudflare

I have a domain at Cloudflare and some wildcards for subdomains

[image]

which both point to the load balancer of an nginx ingress of a Kubernetes cluster (GKE) of the GCP. Now, we have two pods and services running each (echo1 and echo2, which are essentially identical) and when I apply an ingress

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "echo1.eu3.example.com"
    http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: echo1
              port:
                number: 80
  - host: "echo2.example.com"
    http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: echo2
              port:
                number: 80
```

I can reach echo2 under echo2.example.com, but not echo1.eu3.example.com. My question is how I can make the second one reachable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can advise you to make some check.

Just set the Proxy status for "echo1.eu3.example.com" as DNS only. Then check the access. If ok - install certificates in kubernetes via cert manager. We faced some times with this issue and resolved by using 3 deep domains. For instance "echo1-eu3.example.com". It seems cloudfront does not like such domains :) Of course if someone write a solution how to work with deep domains in cloudfront - it would be good practice for us :)